# Is it safe to install SQL Server 2008 R2 and MySQL side-by-side on Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, database, installation

Are there any drawbacks to such a configuration?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

These two databases are totally separate entities and you should have no problems running both of them on the same machine.

Short story: I wanted to test [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) with various database dialects, so I ended up installing these databases on one machine:

- MS SQL server
- MySQL
- PostgreSQL
- Oracle
- DB2

and I had no problems with all of them running at once. Yes, it was a test server and the poor thing was totally running out of memory, but everything did work.

Only imaginable problem you could run into: configuring the same port for multiple databases. But you wouldn't do that, so it's not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the resources they would both consume (memory, disk, cpu); barring any purposeful conflicting configuration (by default they will listen on different ports), it would work fine.

Answer (score 2):

No as far as I know.. I use both MS SQL and MySQL for my websites in the same box and no issues so far (2 years now!)

Answer (score 2):

I have never run into an issue; they really don't step on each others' configurations at all.